# Is there a way to automatically add corresponding website URLs to company names?

Tags: excel, scripting, automation

I have an Excel sheet with over 5.000 company names. I would like to add the corresponding URL of the company's website to these names, but this would be slightly inconvenient to do manually. Would anyone have any idea how this could be done automatically? It might be important to note that I have little to no programming experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We can only help with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a database of the associated URLs it'd be easy to write a script. Hell, if you have the right GUI and they're in the same order, you could copy/paste.

But if you're asking what I think you're asking that's quite a task and I'm not sure you'll find the answer here unless you're willing to post specifics.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. What kind of specifics would you need in this case?

Comment: As I said, if you have a database or list of the URLs already, throwing together a script in whatever language is available to you would be child's play for the people here. Excel imports are easy.

If you don't have that, and you literally want to go down the list, and google the company's name to get their site (and hope it's accurate) then insert that into your file, you're in for a task large enough that most programmers would charge for their time.